# how to enable access to port from network in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, port, jetty, solr

when i "`netstat -an | grep LISTEN`"

i have line:

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:24030         :::*                    LISTEN
```

i want it to be

```
tcp6       0      0 ::24030         :::*                    LISTEN
```

in other words i want to have this port opened to whole LAN, now it is only accesible from local machine

how can i do it?

im on ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your jetty server is listening only on localhost. Change jetty config to listen on all interfaces. Then set rule in your firewall to accept requests on port 24030 for example `sudo ufw allow 24030`

Comment: yup, there is security part of config file, you can just remove it (of course beware of consequences)

Answer (score 0):

And if you need jetty to be visible/accessable from local network in a Eclipse (web, spring, google app engine) development, you just add --address=0.0.0.0 or -a 0.0.0.0 in your Debug configuration/Arguments/Program arguments. Default jetty setting is localhost and as such is visible just on server.

Thanks to **Casual Coder** for pointing me in the right direction!